# WPF: Multibind and Inline Collections

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, data-binding, multibinding

I have the following binding in my GridViewColumn

```
 <GridViewColumn Header="Text" Width="40">
     <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center">
              <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Path=Link}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_OnRequestNavigate">                                                                                                          
                  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LinkDisplayConverter}">    
                      <Binding Path="Property1"/> 
                      <Binding Path="Property2"/> 
                  </MultiBinding>                                                                                                        
              </Hyperlink>  
            </TextBlock>
         </DataTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

I get an runtime error (System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException) saying that Multibindings are not supported by Inline Collections. I need, however, Property1 and Property2 in my converter. I found a similar question but I was not able to match it to my use case.

Any ideas?

Comment: what you have in your converter ?

Comment: I updated my question. In fact I do get a runtime error (exception). I does not matter what I have in my converter - I have a simple one (see above) and get the error.

Comment: The converter isn't relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Hyperlink can only contain Inline elements, e.g. a Run:

```
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Link}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_OnRequestNavigate">                                                                                                          
    <Run>
        <Run.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LinkDisplayConverter}">    
                <Binding Path="Property1"/> 
                <Binding Path="Property2"/> 
            </MultiBinding>                                                                                                        
        <Run.Text>
    <Run>
</Hyperlink>
```